# I could not display image by passing image path ,which is combination of constant and variable in php

Tags: php

``I couldn't display image by passing below path in src,

```
PRODUCT_IMAGE="/opt/lampp/htdocs/Milan_Practice/admin_module_task/User_Profile/admin_module/images/";

$product_image="xiomi.jpg";

<image src="<?php echo PRODUCT_IMAGE.'/'.$product_image?>">
```

Though I got true path by printing above path,but when passing in image then,couldn't display image.
so,help in solve above problem
ThankYou

Comment: _Give me correct solution_ Demands like that are not normally taken well on SO. We are all volunteers here

Comment: What is in `PRODUCT_IMAGE`? What is in `$product_image`? does a file with that name exist in that path.

Comment: We need a bit more code here. like the values of the Constant and the variable.

Comment: Do you know that an image tag is spelt like this **`<img src=....`** and not as `<image....`

Comment: I think we should close this as a typo

Comment: There path in image tag is right & also checked by echo that,but when passing inside the src of image tag,then couldn't display image.

Comment: Any new suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
define("PRODUCT_IMAGE",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/images");
```

One more consideration, use url path instead of server path.

Comment: yes,that's right ,by help of url,image displays but i want display image using server path

Comment: Its better using url path because it works in any OS(Windows,linux mac).

Comment: You are right,But suppose ,if  i change path of images when i move all that images in other new folder,so that time ,I have to again change my assigned url path in my script file,otherwise image will not display

Comment: so to solve that situation,if i declared constant with server path and my path like "define("PRODUCT_IMAGES",$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Milan_Practice/admin_module_task/User_Profile/admin_module/images/")",I just have to change path of constant PRODUCT_IMAGES ,instead of changing path inside the php script index.php,So that I uses Server Path,Thanxx for good suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Your image tag is wrong it should be `<img` and not `<image`

```
<img src="<?php echo PRODUCT_IMAGE.$product_image?>">
```

And you dont need the `. '/'.` in there as your `PRODUCT_IMAGE` contains a slash at the end of it already.

You should also include an `alt` attribute or search engines get a little bitter and twisted.

```
<img alt="maybe the product name in here" src="<?php echo PRODUCT_IMAGE.$product_image?>">
```

You could also try amending the path to be relative to the location of the php file running this

Assuming your code is in the htdocs folder

```
PRODUCT_IMAGE="Milan_Practice/admin_module_task/User_Profile/admin_module/images/";
```

Comment: @Milan Hi, sorry I dont understand

Comment: By using this,still couldn't display image  <img src="<?php echo PRODUCT_IMAGE.$product_image; ?>" height="80px" width="100px">

Comment: @Milan Sorry I still do not understand. Are you saying that works, or that it does not work?

Comment: Well now you must check that the file actually exists in that folder

Comment: @Milan find the path in your sourcecode and tell me that. Knowing that should easily solve your problem

Comment: See amended answer

Comment: @Milan To get a better answer, you gotta show more code than that :/

Comment: @Milan That's the code you already sent. You could start by sending the path of both your code and the image

Comment: @RPaul  define("PRODUCT_IMAGES",$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Milan_Practice/admin_module_task/User_Profile/admin_module/images/");              and selected image name is $product_image

Comment: @Milan the FULL path, that means no variables, just path of BOTH code and image(s)

Comment: "/opt/lampp/htdocs/Milan_Practice/admin_module_task/User_Profile/admin_module"    is path of current php file ||| PRODUCT_IMAGES= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Milan_Practice/admin_module_‌​task/User_Profile/admin_module/images/" ||| $product_image="xiomi.jpg"

Comment: @Check my answer, your path was invalid

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your path leads nowhere. Remember that your path's origin in the src attributes is the folder your file is in, so for example if all your if your code is in `mywebpage/code` and your image is in `mywebpage/images` then you need this path `../images/yourimage.jpg`. Maybe provide your folder structure for me to determine if your path is correct.

**Images Path**

```
 /opt/lampp/htdocs/Milan_Practice/admin_module_task/User_Profile/admin_module/images/
```

**Code Path**

```
/opt/lampp/htdocs/Milan_Practice/admin_module_task/User_Profile/view
```

Your **Path** should simply be `../admin_module/images/`

Comment: I have already declared above path "/opt/lampp/htdocs/Milan_Practice/admin_module_task/User_Profile/admin_module/images/" in PRODUCT_IMAGE and my cuurent script's path is "User_Profile/view/index.php"

Comment: yes,its 200% right & i used it already,bcoz by url path, image displays ,but i want to display image using Constant's path

Comment: @Milan you don't need the constant

Answer (score 0):

The browser cannot access this part of a path:

```
/opt/lampp/htdocs/Milan_Practice/
```

I guess your page Index is in Milan_Practice directory, so the public path needs to start from there, not from the internal server path.

Comment: yes my index.php is inside Your suggested directory path, as below, "/opt/lampp/htdocs/Milan_Practice/admin_module_task/User_Profile/view/index.php"

Comment: So simply remove the "internal" part of the path, making it relative to the Index directory.